# Switch background if hovering and pressing the shift key?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using this code to switch background when hovering an element and pressing the shift key. It works if I hold the shift key down before I enter the element but not if I'm already on the element and pressing the shift key. Ideas? Thanks!

```js
var shiftPressed = null;
$(document).on({
 keydown: function (e) {
  if( e.shiftKey )
  {
     shiftPressed = true;
  }
 },
 keyup: function (e) {
  shiftPressed = false;
 }
});
$('div').on({
   mousemove: function (e) {
    if( shiftPressed )
    {
   $(this).css('backgroundColor', 'red');
    }
    else
    {
   $(this).css('backgroundColor', '');
  }
   },
   mouseover: function (e) {
    if( shiftPressed )
    {
   $(this).css('backgroundColor', 'red');
    }
    else
    {
   $(this).css('backgroundColor', '');
  }
   },
   mouseleave: function (e) {
  $(this).css('backgroundColor', '');
   }
}, 'span');
```

```css
div {
  position:absolut;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:#999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <span>TARGET</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You've got all the necessary components, you just need to store them into some vars. On mouseenter, set `hovering=true` on mouseleave, set it to false, then on keydown set holdingShift=true and so forth, and then for every event that fires, check both vars. If both are set, set the bg, and if not both, clear it.

Comment: Would it be possible to make a quick example? I tried but couldn't get it to work. Thanks!

Comment: Fine fine....see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A div cannot be focused (by default); thus, *it cannot capture key presses*.

However, if you bind the `keypress` event listener to the document, the event will fire on every key press. Keep the `mouseover` and `mouseleave` bound to the div, because they can be fired with a non-focusable element.

Also, *a [keyboard event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) is different than a [mouse event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent)*, so you can't access `shiftKey` of `e` in mouseover. Instead, I would use the `&&` operator to test if both conditions are met: the shift key and the mouse in, storing whether the shift key is pressed in a boolean and checking that on mouseover / mouseleave.

```js
var shiftPressed = null; // global data
$(document).on('keyup keydown', function(e) {
  shiftPressed = e.shiftKey;
  updateDivs();
});

$('div').on({
  mouseover: function(e) {
    $(this).data('hovered', true); // element-specific data
    updateDiv(this);
  },
  mouseleave: function(e) {
    $(this).data('hovered', false); // element-specific data
    updateDiv(this);
  }
});

function updateDiv(div) {
  if (shiftPressed && $(div).data('hovered'))
    $(div).css('backgroundColor', 'red');
  else
    $(div).css('backgroundColor', '');
}
/** updates all divs in document */
function updateDivs() {
  $('div').each(function() {
    updateDiv(this);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Hello world</div>
<div>Hi world</div>
```

Comment: put mouse on the element and than press the key, not going to turn the element red.

Comment: @epascarello no it does not do the same thing that the OP has; I see what you're saying, though, I will update my answer.

Comment: same thing as "it still fails OPs test case just like OPs does" and the shift key does get registered with mouseover....

Comment: I updated my code above to this and what you guys are saying it doesn't work without any mousemovements.

Comment: @clabe45 One more thing. I create the divs dynamically on the page. Any way to make this automatically work on newly created elements?

Comment: @SeaBass use `$(document).on({...}, 'div')` instead of `$('div').on({...})`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a bunch of code to listen to the mouse position and also an event for the keydown and figure out where the cursor is...

There might be a better solution, but this works.

```js
$('div').on("mouseenter", "span", function(e) {
  if (e.shiftKey) {
    $(this).css('backgroundColor', 'red');
  }
}).on("mouseleave", "span", function(e) {
  $(this).css('backgroundColor', 'white');
})

let x = 0;
let y = 0;
$(document).on("mousemove", function(e) {
  x = e.clientX;
  y = e.clientY;
}).on("keydown keyup", function(e) {
  $(document.elementFromPoint(x, y)).trigger({
    type: e.type==="keydown" ? "mouseenter" : "mouseleave",
    shiftKey: true
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span>Test</span>
  <span>Test</span>
  <span>Test</span>
  <span>Test</span>
  <span>Test</span>
  <span>Test</span>
  <span>Test</span>
  <span>Test</span>
  <span>Test</span>
</div>
```

Other way is to set an active element and not worry about the x and y position.

```js
let active;
$('div').on("mouseenter", "span", function(e) {
  active = this;
  if (e.shiftKey) {
    $(this).css('backgroundColor', 'red');
  }
}).on("mouseleave", "span", function(e) {
  console.log(e)

  $(this).css('backgroundColor', 'white');
  if (active && !e.custTrigger && $(this).is(active)) active = null
})

$(document).on("keydown keyup", function(e) {
  if (active) {
    $(active).trigger({
      type: e.type==="keydown" ?"mouseenter" : "mouseleave",
      shiftKey: true,
      custTrigger: true
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span>Test</span>
  <span>Test</span>
  <span>Test</span>
  <span>Test</span>
  <span>Test</span>
  <span>Test</span>
  <span>Test</span>
  <span>Test</span>
  <span>Test</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. In my browser you need to have shift pressed down already before you enter the element. It's not possible if you're already on it.

Comment: Also it stays red when releasing the shift key if still on the element.

Comment: So you add code that fires the leave on keyup and it works fine for me when you are on it and press... You need to make sure that the window has focus for it to pick up the keypress.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit sloppy but it should work. Just set some vars and then check them whenever an event is fired.

N.B. you have to click once inside the iframe to make it work (so that it can capture keypresses). Presumably on your page you're not using an iframe, so that won't be necessary.

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.box'), box => {
  let hover = false;
  let shift = false;
  
  box.addEventListener('mouseenter', ev => {
    hover = true;
    check();
  });

  box.addEventListener('mouseleave', ev => {
    hover = false;
    check();
  });

  document.addEventListener('keydown', ev => {
    shift = ev.shiftKey;
    check();
  });

  document.addEventListener('keyup', ev => {
    shift = ev.shiftKey;
    check();
  });

  function check() {
    box.style.backgroundColor = shift && hover ? 'red' : '';
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #999;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span>TARGET</span>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <span>TARGET</span>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <span>TARGET</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is all good except for it only works for #box, not every .box on the page. Possible to do that? The post below does it, but rather not use each() and things if not necessary.

Comment: @SeaBass Yes, it's possible. You should have put more than one box in your example.

Comment: @SeaBass Updated the code... technically the keyup/down listeners are redundant but I can't think of an easier way to share that variable at the moment. Play with it, it's your code ;)

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, but here's a non jquery example that monitors keystrokes and adds the various shift/ctrl/alt states to the html classList in real time.

css can respond accordingly.

***note***

to test this code in the stackoverflow snippet, focus is required because the snippet runs in an iframe.

when running as a top level page, the current document is focused by default.

first click "Run Code Snippet" and the select the iframe directly below it - click on the word "shift", and you will be focused in the iframe

you can then tap the shift key.

```js
const html = document.querySelector("html");
["keyup","keydown"].forEach(function(ev){
     document.addEventListener(ev,updateHtmlKeyClasses);
});

function updateHtmlKeyClasses(e){
  ["shiftKey","ctrlKey","altKey"].forEach(function(shiftKey){
     html.classList[e[shiftKey]?"add":"remove"](shiftKey);
  });
}
```

```css
div {
   margin :10px;
}

html.shiftKey .shiftstate,
html.ctrlKey .ctrlstate,
html.altKey .altstate {
   background:lime;
}


.test {
  background:cyan;
}


.test:hover {
  background:yellow;
}

html.shiftKey .test:hover {
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="shiftstate">
  shift
</div>

<div class="ctrlstate">
  ctrl
</div>

<div class="altstate">
  alt
</div>

 <div class="test">
 TEST AREA
 </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

[`keypress` doesn't capture the shift-key](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/)

> This [the keypress event] is similar to the keydown event, except that modifier and non-printing keys such as Shift, Esc, and delete trigger keydown events but not keypress events.

Comment: If we remove the keypress part, any way to solve it with any other mouseenter/mouseover/mousemove types?

Comment: @SeaBass Yes. It says it on the page I linked to you and in my answer. Just replace `keypress` with `keydown`

Comment: Adding mousemove instead of keypress is a little closer. Now I only miss the red background on just shift click when having the ouse pointer over the element.

Comment: Did you even read my answer? The problem isn't the `mouseenter`, it's with `keypress`. `keypress` won't get triggered. `mousemove` will fire almost permanently and therefore should work ok (unless you don't move your mouse after pressing shift), but is way overkill

Comment: Yes I did, but keydown still doesn't trigger it when the mouse is still. Maybe I need to change the 'div' and 'span'?

Comment: I updated the post with some other types. I just want it to turn red when the shift key is down and the mouse pointer is over the element.

Comment: This post is not very informative; there are other problems in the code that this answer does not address.